# Return text value

Tags: excel

I would like to know to formula to populate D17 ("First Round Winner") with the name value from C4:C15 ("Team names") compared with AQ4:AQ15 ("Total").

I will have the formula from D17 to AO17 checking the highest value from Total and returning the team names

Can't add image to visualize.

Thank you in advanced

Regards.

Comment: What do you mean by populating a cell with something compared with something else? Do you want a true/false entry? Or some kind of difference? Although you are unable to post an image, an example would really be helpful.

Comment: https://imageshack.com/i/neogg5p 

The image has been uploaded. "Lider" row is what i would like to have value on it from the team names with high score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is to find the max of one column, and return the value of the associated column on the same row.  The formula looks like this:

```
=IF(G8=MAX(G6:G8),H8)
```

Or if the value of G8 = the max of the range, then give me H8.

I tried to show an example of the table...  It looks like this:

```
winner  someother       10  this guy
                        11  that guy
                        12  someother
```

There is a dump of the table where I tested that.  If you are using columns instead of rows, just transpose the idea.

Comment: ok. but i still don't get it. Im trying now to get something like this.

C4 - Team 1 - D4 - 100
C5 - Team 2 - D5 - 80
C6 - Team 3 - D6 - 60

              D8 -Team 1(Team name with highest value between D4:D6)

Comment: Thank You. I did get your example working fine as well but somehow i can't use the same. The best result i get when modifying the formula is FALSE as result.

Comment: If you're getting FALSE, it's because that's the result of the formula.  You may not be referencing the correct cels.

Comment: Thank You. Got it working now. reference was incorrect as you've said.

Comment: Spiffy!  Glad to hear.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but what if i add another column and SUM with H6:H8 with value 13 (this guy), 12 (this guy) and 11 (someother).
The highest value will be 23 for the first guy and i will have to change the formula once again to get the winner?

Comment: Well, yes...  You should always have as many cels in our formula as there are cels to read.  The actual best practice on this that allows for every cell in a row is to reference "1:1" (rownum:rownum).  assuming there is nothing else IN that row, it will work fine.

Comment: Thank You! will have to get some more time to review that